# Thread pausing/resuming implementation

Tags: java, multithreading

I saw [How to wait current thread execution and execute another thread completedly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886977/how-to-wait-current-thread-execution-and-execute-another-thread-completedly) on StackOverflow, and I [answered it there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058395/how-to-pause-thread-execution/6058532#6058532), but would like more eyes on the code I posted.

The requirement is to pause one thread whilst a different thread is running.

Could you please review and comment on this implementation?

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread1 thread1 = new Thread1();
        Thread2 thread2 = new Thread2();

        try {
            thread1.start();
            Thread.sleep(500);
            synchronized (thread1) {
                thread1.waiting = true;
                thread2.start();
                thread2.join();
                thread1.waiting = false;
                thread1.notify();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //TODO actually handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

Class Thread1.java

```
public class Thread1 extends Thread {
    boolean waiting = false;

    public void run() {
        testFun1();
    }

    public void testFun1() {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            synchronized (this) {
                while (waiting) {
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        //TODO Handle exception
                    }
                }
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                System.out.println("From testFun1() = " + i);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //TODO Handle exception

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Class Thread2.java

```
public class Thread2 extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        testFun2();
    }

    public void testFun2() {
        try {
            for (int i = 20; i <= 25; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    //catch
                }
                System.out.println("From testFun2() = " + i);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //TODO do something
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\java -Didea.launcher.port=7543 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 10.5.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\alt-rt.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\alt-string.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\IdeaProjects\PracticeModule\target\classes;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 10.5.1\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain jmhp.core.App
From testFun1() = 1
From testFun1() = 2
From testFun1() = 3
From testFun1() = 4
From testFun1() = 5
From testFun2() = 20
From testFun2() = 21
From testFun2() = 22
From testFun2() = 23
From testFun2() = 24
From testFun2() = 25
From testFun1() = 6
From testFun1() = 7
From testFun1() = 8
From testFun1() = 9
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The implementation looks fine. Some small notes:

1. Consider using [Guava's Uninterruptibles](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Uninterruptibles.html#sleepUninterruptibly%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) class if you don't want to handle `InterruptedException`s.
2. The default access `waiting` flag in `Thread1` is makes the code hard to read/follow and results tight coupling.
3. Consider using `Runnable`s instead of `Thread`s. See: [Java: “implements Runnable” vs. “extends Thread”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/541487/843804)
4. Consider synchronizing on a separate lock object: [Avoid synchronized(this) in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/442564/843804)

Anyway, it would be much easier, less error-prone and more readable with a fair [`Semaphore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) (from the [concurrency utilities package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/overview.html)):

`App.java`:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final Semaphore control = new Semaphore(1, true);

        final Thread1 thread1 = new Thread1(control);
        final Thread2 thread2 = new Thread2();

        thread1.start();
        Uninterruptibles.sleepUninterruptibly(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        control.acquireUninterruptibly();
        thread2.start();
        thread2.join();
        control.release();
    }
}
```

`Thread1.java`:

```
public class Thread1 extends Thread {
    private final Semaphore control;

    public Thread1(final Semaphore control) {
        this.control = control;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            control.acquireUninterruptibly();
            try {
                Uninterruptibles.sleepUninterruptibly(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                System.out.println("From testFun1() = " + i);
            } finally {
                control.release();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Thread2.java`:

```
public class Thread2 extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 20; i <= 25; i++) {
            Uninterruptibles.sleepUninterruptibly(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            System.out.println("From testFun2() = " + i);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot, threads is a extensive theme with lots of things that can be learned! like i just did! :)